# Android AsyncTask Upload Files

Tags: php, android, file-upload, android-asynctask

I want upload a number of files that are stored on the android device but it seems to be stuck in the doInBackground Method of AsyncTask. I get no errors. The Dialog popsup and stays active i eliminated the dialog and no effect. The other part of my project is to decode the json files I uploaded and store them in a database but thats for later.

```
    /********************UPLOAD GPSDATA*************************************/
class UploadGpsData extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>{

    NetworkInfo net;

    MainActivity uActivity;

    HttpURLConnection connection = null;
    DataOutputStream outputStream = null;
    DataInputStream inputStream = null;

    String folderPath;
    String arrayOfFiles[];
    File root;
    File allFiles;

    String urlServer = "http://urluploadscriptaddress.php";
    String lineEnd = "\r\n";
    String twoHyphens = "--";
    String boundary =  "*****";

    int bytesRead, bytesAvailable, bufferSize;
    byte[] buffer;
    int maxBufferSize = 1*1024*1024;

    URL url;

     ProgressDialog pDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);



    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {


        Log.d(" UploadGpsData","onPreRequest");

            pDialog.setMessage("Uploading GPS Data. Please wait...");
            pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            pDialog.setCancelable(true);
            pDialog.show();


    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {

         Log.d(" UploadGpsData","doInBackground");

        root = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(); 

        //pathToOurFile = root.getAbsolutePath()+"/Beagle Data/07-09-2013_16-21-30.json";

        folderPath = root.getAbsolutePath()+"/Beagle Data/";

        allFiles = new File(folderPath);

        arrayOfFiles = allFiles.list(); 




        for(int i = 0; i < arrayOfFiles.length; i++){

            Log.d("File Names", arrayOfFiles[i].toString());
            //File filename = new File(arrayOfFiles[i].toString());
            try {
                url = new URL(urlServer);
            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            try {
                connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            // Allow Inputs & Outputs
            connection.setDoInput(true);
            connection.setDoOutput(true);
            connection.setUseCaches(false);

            // Enable POST method
            try {
                connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
            } catch (ProtocolException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            connection.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
            connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data;boundary="+boundary);
            try{

            FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(new File(folderPath+arrayOfFiles[i].toString()) );
            try {
                outputStream = new DataOutputStream( connection.getOutputStream() );
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            outputStream.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd);
            outputStream.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"uploadedfile\";filename=\"" + folderPath+arrayOfFiles[i].toString() +"\"" + lineEnd);
            outputStream.writeBytes(lineEnd);

            bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
            bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
            buffer = new byte[bufferSize];

            // Read file
            bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);

            while (bytesRead > 0){
                outputStream.write(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
                bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
                bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
                bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);

            }

            outputStream.writeBytes(lineEnd);
            outputStream.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + twoHyphens + lineEnd);

            //int serverResponseCode = connection.getResponseCode();
            //String serverResponseMessage = connection.getResponseMessage();

            // Responses from the server (code and message)
            //serverResponseCode = connection.getResponseCode();
            //serverResponseMessage = connection.getResponseMessage();

            fileInputStream.close();
            outputStream.flush();
            outputStream.close();
            } catch(Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }


    return null;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute() {

         Log.d(" UploadGpsData","onPost");

        pDialog.dismiss();

        txtUploadStatus = (TextView) findViewById(id.txtUploadStatus);

        txtUploadStatus.setText("Upload Achieved");
    }
}
/********************END OF UPLOADGPSDATA*************************************/
```

PHP Script below: The error log is empty so I am assuming its stuck on the android application

```
<?php
$target_path  = "./";

$target_path = $target_path . basename( $_FILES['uploadedfile']['name']);

$file = basename( $_FILES['uploadedfile']['name']);

move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploadedfile']['tmp_name'], $target_path)
?>
```

Comment: Have you tried stepping through the code?

Comment: Yes I have. I have 3 files and in every step I have put a log.d. The last log.d is before the return and it stays there. onPost never is shown.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not implement the @Override onPostExecute.

Modify your onPostExecute assignature with this:

```
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
```

This will resolve your problem.
What was happening:
You are not overriding the OnPostExecute AsyncTask method, was creating a new one.

Comment: Thank you. I have made those corrections and onPost is showing up. But my files aren't being uploaded.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the `params` for `onPostExecute()` may be one problem

```
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
```

Even though you aren't returning anything to it from `doInBackground()` you still need this to be the `AsyncTask` method. If this doesn't fix it then please also post how you are calling it and explain if you have set breakpoints anywhere to see what it is doing.

Comment: I placed the code that you posted and onPost is Showing up. I did the break point from the beginning of the class everything ran good. This is how I call it: new UploadGpsData().execute();Files are still not uploaded. Now I noticed a message pop up in the Log colored in green: Skipped 1034 frames The application may be doing to much work on its main thread.

Comment: So the `AsyncTask` is running successfully now? Unless I'm missing something, I don't see anything that would cause that. Could it be coming from somewhere else in your code, before or after the task runs?

Comment: If I take the for loop out, the one that contains the list of file names, it will upload a single file.

Comment: You might try taking things out of the `for loop` that you don't need to reset every time. Also, how are you calling this task?

Answer (score -1):

You "manipulate" UI in a no-UI thread.

Try to comment all your code related to UI, it should work.

You can use

```
Context.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() ....
```

In order to do UI stuff.

Comment: The functions that @frankiebp is using from AsyncTask do get executed on the UI thread. See http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html, the 4 steps.